# Block with div structure begin outputted not properly

Tags: html, css

I have next problem :

[image]

I have this html structure:

```
<aside> 
<!-- ...... -->
    <div class='block'>
        <div class='header'><h1>Новости</h1></div>
        <div class='content'>
            <div>
                <label>bob</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>bob</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- ...... -->
</aside>
```

And this css structure:

```
aside label {
    color: #ffcc33;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 80%;
}

aside label.login {
    text-align: right;
}

aside form input {
    float: right;
}

aside > div.block > div.content div {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

aside > div.block > div.content div+div {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Why parent block is so small, like there are no any data in it? There are some, but it is still shown like no.

Answer (score 2):

You need a clearfix. Try Nicolas Gallagher's [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/):

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using clearfix in another place, but didn't get that it could help me here too.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `<div class='content'>` element. It collapses because of the floated children.

Comment: Mhm. Worked. Thank you. Can you explain it please?

Comment: When you float the children they essentially are removed from the flow of the document and the parent therefore collapses and has no height. Adding overflow:auto restores the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer a bit later. I can't now.